# Regex command line change format of each line

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu, sed, gawk

I have a file that contains lines in a format similar to this...

```
/data/file.geojson?10,20,30,40
/data/file.geojson?bbox=-5.20751953125,49.05227025601607,3.0322265625,56.46249048388979
/data/file.geojson?bbox=-21.46728515625,45.99696161820381,19.2919921875,58.88194208135912
/data/file.geojson?bbox=-2.8482055664062496,54.38935426009769,-0.300750732421875,55.158473983815306
/data/file.geojson?bbox=-21.46728515625,45.99696161820381,19.2919921875,58.88194208135912
/data/file.geojson?bbox=-21.46728515625,45.99696161820381,19.2919921875,58.88194208135912
```

I've tried a combination of `grep`, `sed`, `gawk`, and `|`(pipes) to try and pattern match and then change  the format to be more like this...

```
[10,40],[30,40],[30,20][10,20],
[-5.20751953125,56.46249048388979],[3.0322265625,56.46249048388979].....
```

Hopefully you get the idea from the first line so I don't have to type out all the examples manually!

I've got the hang of regex to match the co-ordinates. In fact the input file is the result of extracting from apache access logs. It might be easier to read/understand answers if they just match positive integer numbers, I will then be able to slot in a more [complicated pattern to match the right range](https://gist.github.com/nomoregrapes/f82f0571ec500c39014d).

Comment: Do you always have 2 pairs of numbers after the string?

Comment: Don't show us sample input that is "in a format **similar to**" and desired output that is "more like" your real files, show us sample input and output that IS in the format of your real files. Otherwise you'll probably get an answer that solves some completely different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to arrange the results like you which it is important to be able to access the last for values per line.

No pattern matching is required if you use `awk`. You can split the input strings by a set of delimiters and reassemble the resulting fields. `40` can be accessed as `$(NF)`, `30` as `$(NF-1)` and so on.

```
awk -F'[?,=]' '
    {printf "[%s,%s],[%s,%s],[%s,%s],[%s,%s]\n",
        $(NF-3),$(NF),$(NF-1),$(NF),
        $(NF-1),$(NF-2),$(NF-3),$(NF-2)
    }' file
```

I'm using `?`, `,` or `=` as the field delimiters. This makes it simple to access the columns of interest.

Output:

```
[10,40],[30,40],[30,20],[10,20]
[-5.20751953125,56.46249048388979],[3.0322265625,56.46249048388979],[3.0322265625,49.05227025601607],[-5.20751953125,49.05227025601607]
[-21.46728515625,58.88194208135912],[19.2919921875,58.88194208135912],[19.2919921875,45.99696161820381],[-21.46728515625,45.99696161820381]
[-2.8482055664062496,55.158473983815306],[-0.300750732421875,55.158473983815306],[-0.300750732421875,54.38935426009769],[-2.8482055664062496,54.38935426009769]
[-21.46728515625,58.88194208135912],[19.2919921875,58.88194208135912],[19.2919921875,45.99696161820381],[-21.46728515625,45.99696161820381]
[-21.46728515625,58.88194208135912],[19.2919921875,58.88194208135912],[19.2919921875,45.99696161820381],[-21.46728515625,45.99696161820381]
```

---

Btw, also `sed` can be used here:

```
sed -r 's/.*[?=]([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),(.*)/[\1,\4],[\3,\4],[\3,\2],[\1,\2]/' file
```

The command is capturing the numbers at the end each in a separate capturing group and re-assembles them in the replacement part.

Not all versions of `sed` support the `+` quantifier. The most compatible version would look like this :)

```
sed 's/.*[?=]\([^,]\{1,\}\),\([^,]\{1,\}+\),\([^,]\{1,\}\),\(.*\)/[\1,\4],[\3,\4],[\3,\2],[\1,\2]/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

sed strips off items prior to numbers, then awk splits on comma and outputs in different order.  Assuming data is in a file called "td.txt"

```
sed 's/^[^0-9-]*//' td.txt|awk -F, '{print "["$1","$4"],["$3","$4"],["$3","$2"],["$1","$2"],"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^.*\?[^-0-9]*([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)/[\1,\4],[\3,\4],[\3,\2],[\1,\2]/' file
```

Or with more `toothpicks`:

```
sed 's/^.*\?[^-0-9]*\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/[\1,\4],[\3,\4],[\3,\2],[\1,\2]/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match:

```
(\/data\/file\.geojson\?(?:bbox=)?)([0-9.-]+),([0-9.-]+),([0-9.-]+),([0-9.-]+)
```

And replace with the following:

```
$1[$2,$3],[$4,$5]
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tE9sU6/1)

Comment: This answer is incomplete, as you haven't actually shown how to solve the problem, you've just come up with a regex that won't work on any of the tools that the OP has tagged the question with.